# What extra functionality is available to an IBM Q Network member over a regular IBM Q Experience user

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I've been trying to figure out the extra functionality available to `IBM Q Network` members that are not available to normal `IBM Q Experience` users.

I couldn't find anything that says that Network members have access to better quantum processors or perhaps access to functionality within the Qiskit library that isn't available to Experience users.

Could someone please list all the benefits of having Network membership?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically being IBM Q Network member give you the possibility to access IBM’s most-powerful quantum computing systems through the cloud (currently 20Q, 27Q, 28Q, 53Q devices with Quantum Volume between 8 and 32 depending the device). Some of the premium devices are visible in this post: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2020/07/qv32-performance/
Depending on your engagement you also have access to different levels of collaboration from simple support to joint development.
No special qiskit library for IBM Q Network but special content/documentation and education materials.
Note that between the common user and the IBM Q Network member there is also a new way to engage for academic researchers: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2020/07/quantum-researcher-program/